# Use an inaudible sound to verify if speaker is working on a mobile device?

Tags: audio, safari, ios

Specifically we have this problem where sound should be playing in Safari 14 but it is not. This is not a user-interaction problem, it's part of a video/audio stream. It's an intermittent problem but happens more often than not. Sound makes it to the browser but it often doesn't play.

The problem is apparently browsers have no way to tell if sound is coming out of a speaker. So my thought is if you can play a reference sound (not audible to humans) and that sound can confirm that the speaker is working (by the device's mic).

I'm just skeptical if it would actually work regarding audio reflection based on surrounding.

Anyway I will check our implementation make sure there's no race condition going on or something (regarding user input) but just this idea, I'm curious if it could work, anyone with audio experience.

Comment: Why not open the system preferences and sound input, then watch the mic activity when something is playing.

Comment: Both (ordinary) speakers and microphones are optimized for *audible* frequencies, especially the voice band.  Infrasonic and/or ultrasonic (i.e. what is *"inaudible"*) reproduction by a speaker and/or capture by a microphone would require high-quality devices not found in a typical PC/laptop.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153280/android-transmit-a-signal-using-ultrasound/20153551

Comment: Plus, you'd have to ask user permission to access the mic. Many people would find that suspicious & deny. Why not a 'Can you hear this beep?' yes/no button instead.

Comment: This is a video/audio chat application so it's already expected to use both. It's just for whatever reason Safari/iPhone sometimes doesn't work. Anyway yeah I'll probably avoid this as a solution then sucks.